# Adaptive carousel html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel

I have a carousel with multiple images on every slide, but I want there to be one image only when viewing on phone, and more images as the screen gets larger. is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [slick carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) to do this.

Third demo will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect iphone with this : 
than add static image that you want to view on iPhone.

```
  function isiPhone(){
        return (
            (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPhone") != -1) ||
            (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPod") != -1)
        );
    }
    if(isiPhone()){
       // add static image code
       alert('iPhone detected');
    }
```